# Corrupt access front end accdb after mixing office versions

Tags: ms-access, vba, corrupt

I have a problem with a DB I started work on a couple of years ago in Access 2010. I fired it up last week and now I'm getting an "unrecognized database format" error when I try and open the front end.

I left this project sat after the company lost interest in finishing it. Since then I worked on another project on the same dev machine which required me to install Access 2007. I had both 2010 and 2007 installed at the same time and I remember opening the now problematic db to take some snippets from some code in there for use in the other project. Im pretty sure I only opened it in 2010 at that time.

Now the company has shown interest again I need to finish the project.

Ive tried uninstalling all instances of Office and the Access Database Engine (I needed this to test the 2007 project) running a clean up and putting a fresh install of 2010 back, but Im still getting the same error. Ive tried importing the objects from the accdb file into a new db but access still throws the unrecognized database format error. The same error is given if I try to decompile as well.

Today Ive tried uninstalling office 2010 and putting a clean 2007 install to see if I can open/decompile/import from the older db under that version of access but Im faced with the same error.

The file server where I backed up to has been rebuilt since I worked on the original project and I thought that the accdb file might have been corrupted during this process as Im pulling it from the old vhd. I've also pulled backups from several locations and all the files give me the same error. Ive even tried running them on one of the clients where I know it used to work and has not been had office tampered with since I was last looking at this and still I get the same error. I know that I had compact and repair on exit set on the front end and Im wondering if I managed to inadvertently use 2007 and the last time I opened it and royally screwed it up unknowingly creating a little surprise for me here two years down the track!

I have even tried installing an "Access Recovery Toolbox" util to see what that could make of the file, and it pulls absolutely nothing back in the report.

I have a much older version of the db which works on my dev machine but Im at a massive loss if I have to start work from this version as I made some very significant changes between these versions including changes to the back end table structure.

Any light anyone can shine, even if it just means getting the VBA out into a text file would be really helpful!!

TIA

Comment: With the file I uploaded isolated I can get it to open. I have since found a more recent backup which I cannot for the life of me get to open under any circumstance.

Would one of you be kind enough to give it a spin?

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3...bGs&authuser=0

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a new DB and pulling in the tables, forms, etc from the bad DB?  I would recommend doing it incrementally and checking the new DB after each import.  IE just bring in the tables and then see if they are healthy before moving on.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your message.

I have tried doing this, but at the point I select the old accdb file from the import wizard within the new database I get the same error before It even pulls the content from the old file.

Comment: I would baseline the environment as much as possible.  Being a Network type I see this a no prob, some might say WTF.  New box, OS, install of Access.  Then copy DB to this machine and try the import again.  Vitalization is great for this if you can.

Comment: I just found a vanilla win7 vhd kicking around so I fired it up and did a clean install of access 2010 but I still got the exact same error when trying to open or import from the accdb file. I tried applying Office SP1 and then SP2 and still came up with the same. I then tried installing all the office updates after SP2 and retesting still getting the unrecgonized format error...

Comment: Does anyone else want to chime in see if they can help me on this? I'm at my wits end!!

Comment: Sorry that I am not good at this type of this without it being in front of me.  Have you tried talking to MS?

Comment: Ive uploaded a version of the failing DB to my dropbox here

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3...bGs&authuser=0

If anyone has 5 minutes to try and open in, or pass any tools you might have kicking around over it to see if I can get the VBA back from the forms I would REALLY appreciate it!